# Java Futures: Could someone explain me the program flow

Tags: java, java-7, future

I am fine with javascript promises. So I wanted to try out Java Futures (still stuck in java 7). But these Java Futures don't make sense to me. Here is a trimmed and modified version of [journaldev](http://www.journaldev.com/1650/java-futuretask-example-program):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FutureTest {
    static class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
        private long waitTime;
        MyCallable(int timeInMillis){
            this.waitTime=timeInMillis;
        }
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            return Thread.currentThread().getName();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyCallable callable1 = new MyCallable(500);
        MyCallable callable2 = new MyCallable(1000);
        FutureTask<String> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<String>(callable1);
        FutureTask<String> futureTask2 = new FutureTask<String>(callable2);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executor.execute(futureTask2);
        executor.execute(futureTask1);

        while (true) {
            try {
                boolean done1 = futureTask1.isDone();
                boolean done2 = futureTask2.isDone();

                if(futureTask1.isDone() && futureTask2.isDone()){
                    System.out.println("Done");
                    executor.shutdown();
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println("Done1:" + done1 + " - 2:" + done2);

                String x = futureTask1.get(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if (x != null)
                    System.out.println("FutureTask1 output="+x);
                else
                    System.out.println("Waiting for FutureTask1");

                String s = futureTask2.get(200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(s != null)
                    System.out.println("FutureTask2 output="+s);
                else
                    System.out.println("Waiting for FutureTask2");

                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(TimeoutException e) {} 
        }
    }
}
```

The output of it is:

```
Done1:false - 2:false
Done1:false - 2:false
Done1:false - 2:false
Done1:false - 2:false
Done1:false - 2:false
FutureTask1 output=pool-1-thread-2
Done1:true - 2:false
FutureTask1 output=pool-1-thread-2
Done1:true - 2:false
FutureTask1 output=pool-1-thread-2
FutureTask2 output=pool-1-thread-1
Done
```

Why are the `Waiting for FutureTaskX` System-outs not executed? I would expect the main thread to loop and System-out `Waiting for ...` until the Futures are resolved.

I'm not interested in different ways of solving this problem, only in the program flow of this code. Thanks.

Comment: *Please* get in the habit of using braces even for one-line blocks. It will save you lots of mistakes, and is easier for the rest of us to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code never reaches the "Waiting for FutureTask1" line.

If `futureTask1.get` does not return a value within the timeout, a `TimeoutException` is thrown.

The only time that it returns without throwing an exception, `x` and `s` are no longer null.

See the [FutureTask get documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Answer (score 1):

Since `futureTask1.get(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` will throw `TimeoutException`, for the `futureTask1` sleep time is `500` millseconds, `futureTask2` has the same issue.

Maybe you need output `Waiting for FutureTask` in `TimeoutException` catch clause, and `sleep` in `finally` block, maybe like:

```
try {
...
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
   System.out.println("Waiting for FutureTask");
} finally {
   Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: That empty catch block left me in the dark.